# How to produce messages from public computers to a Kafka installation on a private network?

Tags: apache-kafka, hortonworks-data-platform

The system on which my Kafka server is running has two NICs, one with a public IP (135.220.23.45) and the other with a private one (192.168.1.14). The private NIC is connected to a subnet composed of 7 machines in total (all with addresses 192.168.1.xxx). Kafka has been installed as a service using HDP and has been configured with zookeeper.connect=192.168.1.14:2181 and listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.14:6667. I have started a consumer on the system that hosts the kafka server using: [bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 192.168.1.14:6667 --topic test --from-beginning].

When I start producers (using [bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 192.168.1.14:6667 --topic test]) on any of the machines on the private subnet the messages are received normally by the consumer.

I would like to start producers on public systems and receive the messages by the consumer running on the kafka server. I believed that this could be achieved by IP masquerading and by forwarding all external requests to 135.220.23.45:15501 (I have chosen 15501 to receive kafka messages) to 192.168.1.14:6667. To that extend I setup this port forwarding rule on firewalld: [port=15501:proto=tcp:toport=6670:toaddr=192.168.1.14].

However, this doesn’t seem to work since when I start a producer on an external system with [bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 135.220.23.45:15501 --topic] the messages cannot be received by the consumer.

I have tried different kafka config settings for listeners and advertised.listeners but none of them worked. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define different endpoints for your internal and external traffic in order for this to work. As it is currently configured, when you connect to 135.220.23.45:15501 Kafka would reply with "please talk to me on 192.168.1.14:6667 which is not reachable from the outside and everything from there on out fails.

With [KIP-103](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-103%3A+Separation+of+Internal+and+External+traffic) Kafka was extended to cater to these scenarios by letting you define multiple endpoints. 
Full disclosure, I have not yet tried this out, but something along the following lines should at least get you started down the right road.

```
advertised.listeners=EXTERNAL://135.220.23.45:15501,INTERNAL://192.168.1.14:6667
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
listener.security.protocol.map=EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
```

**Update:**

I've tested this on a cluster of three ec2 machines out of interest. I've used the following configuration:

```
# internal ip: 172.31.61.130
# external ip: 184.72.211.109

listeners=INTERNAL://:9092,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT://:9094
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://172.31.61.130:9092,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT://184.72.211.109:9094
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
```

And that allowed me to send messages from both an internal machine as well as my laptop at home:

```
# Create topic 
kafka-topics --create --topic testtopic --partitions 9 --replication-factor 3 --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181

# Produce messages from internal machine
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-61-130 ~]$ kafka-console-producer --broker-list 127.0.0.1:9092 --topic testtopic                                                                                                               
>internal1
>internal2
>internal3

# Produce messages from external machine
➜  bin ./kafka-console-producer --topic testtopic --broker-list 184.72.211.109:9094
external1
external2
external3

# Check topic
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-61-130 ~]$ kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server 172.31.52.144:9092 --topic testtopic --from-beginning
external3
internal2
external1
external2
internal3
internal1
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. I tried different configuration settings for all the above, plus other suggestions I found on other forums, but couldn't make it work. At the end I set the external host/port as the listener, which works for my requirements.

Comment: Thats weird, I just tried it on a couple of ec2 machines and it worked like a charm. I'll update the config above with my exact values and commands.

Comment: Many thanks, I tried the configuration and for some reason, I get the error: "Connection failed: [Errno 111] Connection refused to :15501"

Comment: Can you maybe update your question with the entire config used and the commands that you are executing? That would make troubleshooting a bit easier.